# Python dependency injection

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I have 3 modules: A, B, C

```
A contains a set of classes that B has fetchers for.

B contains a bunch of singletons that just deal with caching created objects and providing them when requested. Essentially just fetchers.

C is a list of functions that requires instances of A.
```

The operation that I need to do is something along the lines of:

```
C::SomeFunc():
   B.getInstance("instance ID")


B::getInstance(someID: str) -> A:
   -look at cache, which is either [] or {}
   -if it is in cache, return that, else do:  A(someID)
```

My question is, how would you pass around the instances of these modules around? This question is primarily motivated by my lack of understanding of Python's memory allocation system.

I could do something along the lines of constructor-based dependency injection to get an instance of A,B,C where they need to go, and then have some "master/god/controller" object that just passes things where they need to go -

eg:

```
class god(object):
    def __init__(self):
        a = A()
        b = B()
        c = C(b)
.....
.....
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, B_instance):
         self.B = B_instance
    def SomeFunc(self, instanceID):
         self.B.getInstance(instanceID)
```

but this seems like a hack.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've seen some packages that offer an instance provider on [there on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=dependency%20injection&submit=search) if that's what you are looking for. Personally, I didn't want to deal with another object to obtain instances. So I created my own library for this (Python 3 only). You only need **@inject** and annotations.

```
from py3njection import inject
from some_package import ClassToInject

class Demo:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, object_to_use: ClassToInject):
        self.dependency = object_to_use

demo = Demo()
```

You can find it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py3njection).
It basically makes a new instance each time the method is called.

Testing is easy with this since you only have to pass mocks as arguments to unittest your function/method.

I've added **@singleton** too.

If you need even more instantiation ways, like the cache system you're describing, the docs explain how to easily implement your own. Everything cache related would be taken care of in a factory, and the objects that depends on them wouldn't have to know how to get them.

But if you're on Python 2 or if you need to have more control on injections, [this could work too](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dependency_injector/1.12.0). But you still have to manipulate a provider.

Comment: I am intrigued by how you're storing a reference to the `singleton` instance inside a `classmethod`. I've never seen a dependency injected through a static method. For the sake of ensuring finite lifetime and reducing global access, do you think it is possible to store the `singleton` in a container, rather than in a static method? For instance, would it be a trivial change storing it in a separate class that more traditionally manages the dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [injectable](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable) for that. It's a dependency injection autowiring micro-framework.

This is what your code would look like:

```py
@injectable(singleton=True)
class MySingleton:
    ...
```

```py
@autowired
def func_that_needs_my_singleton(my_singleton: Autowired(MySingleton)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently released a small library that might help you achieve this. Feedback is very welcome :D

https://github.com/suned/serum